# How can I process many time series to determine which are oscillating?

Tags: computational-physics, data-analysis

I have a simulated system of many particles (440) and want to determine if any of their velocities are oscillating or showing oscillatory behavior.

I've tried looking at each of the velocity time series individually to check for oscillations but this is practically very inefficient. Can I automate this process somehow using Python/C/Bash (my coding skills)? I've tried Fourier transforming each time series but that still requires looking at many plots to check for spikes.

The picture shows the system which is intended to model a 2D granular material undergoing simple shear. (Lines are contact forces and colors indicate contribution to the Lyapunov vector.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track. Looking at the Fourier spectrum of the individual time series is definitely the way to go, all you need is a suitable peak detection algorithm. You can implement your own, or use the ones already available.

If you want to implement your own, there are a bunch of reviews on the topic, for example [this paper](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/track/pdf/10.1186/1471-2105-10-4.pdf).

However, you can also use already implemented peak detection algorithms in Python, such as for instance SciPy's [peak detection algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)

There are many related posts to this topic on the [signal processing stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peak-detection), so you might find more useful recommendations there.

Comment: Thanks! :) This is helpful.